# Максимально возможное заполнение в клеточном автомате "Life"

Tags: алгоритм

Меня интересует алгоритм вычисления максимально возможного количества "живых" клеток на поле размером 100х100. Предполагается, что это поле - развернутый тор. Стартовое и конечное положения меня не интересуют. Но это  должно быть возможное игровое состояние - т.е. состояние, соответствующее правилам (а не, например, просто заполненный квадрат 100x100). Интересует именно максимум. Возможно, кто-то логически объяснит, что может быть именно такое-то число и не больше ни меньше.

Возможно, многие знают правила игры. Но я их повторю:

> 1) в пустой (мёртвой) клетке, рядом с которой ровно три живые клетки, зарождается жизнь;
>
> 2) если у живой клетки есть две или три живые соседки, то эта клетка
>   продолжает жить;
>
> 3) в противном случае (если соседей меньше двух или больше трёх) клетка
>   умирает («от одиночества» или «от перенаселённости»)

**Уточнение:** Дабы не было никому обидно (и были понятны комменты), правку вношу в виде уточнения, а не меняя непосредственно сам вопрос.

Мне необходимо реальное промежуточное состояние. То, которое может быть достигнуто в принципе. При этом, хотелось бы знать максимально возможное количество живых особей в популяции. Да, действительно, это состояние может быть конечными или цикличным. Но меня не интересует стартовое состояние, когда оно соответствует правилам старта, но, на самом деле, оно не может быть получено иным путем.

Даже скажу больше... возможно, это состояние (состояние максимума популяции для квадрата 100x100) может быть достигнуто из расчета, что первоначальный квадрат был больше. Хотя желательно, чтобы он был ограничен в размерах и был тором.

Отвечая на вопрос, что значит *"возможное игровое состояние"* отмечу, что в моем понимании, стартовое состояние является как бы предигровым состоянием или стартовым состоянием, но не состоянием, полученным в процессе игры. *"Возможное игровое состояние"* в данном случае мной понимается как состояние, полученное в процессе игры.

Возможно, кто-то и не согласен с моим пониманием игрового состояния, но такое оно и есть. Представьте, что гости собираются и рассаживаются за стол (даже уже сели). Но это не застолье. Вот как-то так.

Если предлагаемая популяция циклична, то, может быть, имеет смысл сократить размер поля до 10x10?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37111/discussion-on-question-by-max-zs------).